# How to create a generic method to populate List<SelectListItem> with specified model properties?

Tags: c#, linq, generics

As part of a generic repository I am trying to create a generic method that will populate a list of SelectListItems with the values of specified properties.

I would like to create something like this:

```
public List<SelectListItem> AllAsSelectListItemsSpecifyProperties(Expression<Func<T, string>> valueProperty, Expression<Func<T, string>> textProperty, string selectedValue = "")
{
    return AllAsQueryable().Select(i => new SelectListItem()
    {
        Value = valueProperty.ToString(),
        Text = textProperty.ToString(),
        Selected = (selectedValue == valueProperty)
    })
    .ToList();
}
```

**Usage:**

```
public List<SelectListItem> People()
{
    return AllAsSelectListItemsSpecifyProperties(m => m.ID, m => m.Name, "Ted");
}
```

**Hoped for Result:**

I would like the usage above to return an `List<>` of `SelectListItems` such as this:

```
List<SelectListItem>(){
    {Value: "1", Text: "Ted", Selected: true},
    {Value: "2", Text: "Sam", Selected: false},
    {Value: "3", Text: "Tracy", Selected: false}
};
```

---

**Update**

I think I may have been unclear.  Or perhaps done something wrong.

The answers below are giving returning an object like this:

```
List<SelectListItem>(){
    {Value: "ID", Text: "Name", Selected: true},
    {Value: "ID", Text: "Name", Selected: false},
    {Value: "ID", Text: "Name", Selected: false}
};
```

---

*Is what I'm trying to do possible, and - if so - would anybody be kind enough to point out what I'm doing wrong?*

Comment: What is the type of `AllAsQueryable()`?

Comment: 1) Since you are doing valueProperty.ToString() that's why you are getting value as "m.ID.ToString()" as valueProperty as valueProperty is an expression instead of primitive data type or object. 2) If you can change your implementation to `Expression<Func<T, TModel>> valueProperty` then it will be generic and after compiling and evaluating the expression you can get the actual data type which will your problem 2.

Comment: AllAsQueryable will be an `IQueryable<T>` in a generic repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get property value using expression, you can Compile the expression, then you will have a Func, and you can execute that Func to get the value, like that:

```
public List<SelectListItem> AllAsSelectListItemsSpecifyProperties(Expression<Func<T, string>> valueProperty, Expression<Func<T, string>> textProperty, string selectedValue = "")
{
    return AllAsQueryable().Select(i => new SelectListItem()
    {
        Value = GetPropertyValue(valueProperty),
        Text = GetPropertyValue(textProperty),
        Selected = (selectedValue == valueProperty)
    })
    .ToList();
}

private string GetPropertyValue(Expression<Func<T, string>> expression)
{
    return expression.Compile()(this).ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm sorry I may have been unclear. I was hoping to populate the select list items with property values, not the name.  I have updated the question to make this clearer.

Comment: @MartinHansenLennox Ok, I changed my answer to fix your question.

Comment: @MartinHansenLennox You welcome, it was my pleasure to help you!

Answer (score 1):

You can write a method as shown below to get the value from Expression to create List.

```
public List<SelectListItem> AllAsSelectListItemsSpecifyProperties(Expression<Func<T, string>> valueProperty, Expression<Func<T, string>> textProperty, string selectedValue = "")
{
    return AllAsQueryable().Select(i => new SelectListItem()
    {
        Value = GetValue(valueProperty.Body as MemberExpression).ToString(),
        Text = GetValue(textProperty.Body as MemberExpression).ToString(),
        Selected = (selectedValue == valueProperty)
    })
    .ToList();
}


private object GetValue(MemberExpression member)
{
    var objectMember = Expression.Convert(member, typeof(object));

    var getterLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(objectMember);

    var getter = getterLambda.Compile();

    return getter();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.  I'm sorry, I think I may have been unclear about the desired outcome, or done something wrong.  The select options are giving me the name of the property, not the value. I've updated the question to make it clearer.